# I need OCR for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, ocr, inkcanvas

I need OCR component for InkCanvas control in WPF so I can recognize characters and replaced hand writing one with good one from OCR ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need a good OCR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641173/i-need-a-good-ocr)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has 2 dll for analyzing hand writing in InkCanvas 
"IAWinFX.dll" and
"Microsoft.Ink.Analysis"
and there is an open source example

http://khason.net/blog/ink-recognition-in-wpf/

Comment: Hey bloke the inks broke :p